# New nav seems to forget items per page

Tags: discussion, bug, new-nav, pagination

For years I had a link on my browser toolbar that brought up a filtered list of questions.  Once I selected 50/page I never had to reset the items/page unless I logged out (which I never do deliberately).

With the new nav that link has become

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20xml%20perl%20xslt?mode=any
```

Except now, every time I hit that link the items/page resets to 15. If I'm quick I can scroll down to the bottom of the page during load and actually *see* it changing.  The sequence of events appears to be:

1. The main body loads (with only 15 questions), but the items/page button still says 50.
2. The right sidebar reloads
3. The button resets to 15/page.

[Here's a video](http://www.jhmg.net/misc/stackexchange/SO-ItemsPerPage.mp4).  I start with an empty tab, with SO not loaded in any tabs in the browser.  Previously I had set items/page to 50.

Is this by design, or a bug?

Comment: Just tested on Edge and I can confirm this behavior

Comment: I've been seeing this behavior in Firefox and Chrome for a couple of weeks now. Also (possibly related, possibly not), web sockets are no longer working on SO - I no longer get notifications when new questions are posted. They work in chat, and on other SE sites, just not the main site.

Comment: Why was this marked as a dupe when the linked question doesn't have any answers, fewer votes, and much lower page views? If anything, the other question could be a dupe of this one, or they could be merged.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed.